# Is Ionic framework's compatible with tsconfig target ES2020

Tags: ionic-framework, compatibility, ecmascript-2020

I am using mono repo with npm workspaces. Repo has 3 packages

1. server - server code
2. commons - common code shared between server and ionic-app
3. ionic-app - ionic app

Both server and commons app are configured with target of ‘ES2020’ as follows.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["ES2020"],
  }
}
```

But ionic react app which uses commons package has target of ‘es5’. To match with commons tsconfig, if I change target of ionic app to “ES2020” and module to ‘commonjs’, will there be any compatibility issue while running app in mobile platform (especially older mobile)?

Answer (score 0):

I did tried to use the `es2020` instead of `es5` and couldn't find any error.

Also, when running `ng update` to the angular v14, it will change it automatically to this version.

So for me **it's safe to be use**.

#### Compatibility issue

Ionic is meant to be used by older smartphone, the newest ECMAScript version (the 2020) does contains some logics that **does not work on every devices** (specific the older one).

Please, have a look here: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/ and scroll down to the `2020 features`.